# How to adjust buttons around a textblock?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to get the two buttons (phaseBackButton on the left, and phaseForwardButton on the right) that I have to stick to the sides of the textblock (PhaseDisplay) located on the top left of the screen. For example, when PhaseDisplay enlarges for the word Application, I want the two arrow buttons on the side to adjust with it, instead of cutting it off/ overlapping it. I have read several posts on this topic but none of them have touched on this topic specifically.

[image: Picture of the program]

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="PhaseDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,81,0,0" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button x:Name="PhaseForwardButton" Click="PhaseForward" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="21" Width="21">
    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="Phase_Forward_Icon" />
</Button>
<Button x:Name="PhaseBackButton" Click="PhaseBack" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="21" Width="21">
    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="Phase_Back_Icon" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you actually want. It's not clear what "stick to the sides" means in this context, nor is it clear which `TextBlock` it is you want the buttons to stick to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ill see if I can be a bit more specific